# I am almost done, CAN SOMEONE MY JAVA CODE?

Tags: java

```
package com.unisa.pf.sp52016.assign01;

import com.unisa.pf.sp52016.assign01.Predator.STATUS;

/**
 * <strong>Overview</strong><p>
 * This code comprises a component of a larger game.  You have been asked to implement the structure 
 * that maintains a group of Predators that could be a Pack of friendlies or enemies.  Your task is 
 * to produce the central class that will reflect the status of the Pack.   It is assumed that once 
 * a Predator dies it disappears from the game world.  They travel in a group so there is the possibility
 * that they could all be damaged in one area of effect spell.  Your code should handle the tracking 
 * of the relative health of all the Pack members.  You have been supplied with the specification for 
 * the group (this file) you have also been allocated the specification for an individual Predator.  
 * You do not need to write any code but inside the Pack.java file.  You cannot change the method signatures
 * or the class name.  You simply need to fill in the details for each method in the Pack.java class.
 * You will be provided with the skeleton of the code as a starting point.
 * <p>
 * <strong>Data Structure</strong><p>
 * To make your life easier you will be provided with an API specification 
 * (just like the JavaDocs you use for your programming).  You must use a Predator array to store your 
 * Predators in your Class. You are not permitted to use any collection Classes in this assignment. You 
 * will need to implement the entire class based on the API specification. This class will encapsulate 
 * all the functionality required.  Each method will contain a list of the permissible method calls. I
 * have also left an indication of the length of a solution.  Your solution could be shorter or longer its
 * just an indication so that you can get an idea of how long "a" solution was.
 * <p>
 * <strong>Testing</strong><p>
 * A test program is also provided for you to use.  Please read it carefully as you will be expected
 * to generate your own in assignment 2.  Use the test driver as a starting point to test your Class
 * as thoroughly as possible.  Note that the marker reserves the right to test more conditions 
 * if they think of them.
 * <p>
 * <strong>How to Do The Assignment</strong><p>
 * I suggest you do your assignment in the following order
 * <ul>
 * <li>Compile and make sure that the program works (well, technically it won't because the methods are empty, 
 * but make sure it compiles with no errors). 
 * <li>Write the constructors.  Test.
 * <li>Write the increaseArray method. Test.
 * <li>Write the addPredator method. Test.
 * <li>Write the decreaseArray method. Test.
 * <li>Write the removePredator -int- method. Test.
 * <li>Write the indexOf method. Test.
 * <li>Write the removePredator -String- method. Test.
 * <li>Write the findPredator method. Test.
 * <li>Write the getPredator method. Test.
 * <li>Write the getNumberOfPredators method. Test.
 * <li>Write the totalHitPointsEntirePack method. Test.
 * <li>Write the heal method. Test.
 * <li>Write the damagePredator method. Test.
 * <li>Write the PackDamage method. Test.
 * <li>Write the mostDamagedPredator method. Test.
 * <li>Write the The Rest of the methods. Test.
 * <li>Write the doBattle method. Test.
 * </ul>
 * <p>
 * Note that when you add functionality you may have to add test scenarios to other test methods to 
 * ensure you have covered all the possibilities. 
 * <p>
 * <strong>Additional Requirement.</strong><p>
 * In addition to what is above there are a number of requirements for this assignment. Most of these are 
 * to introduce interesting problems for you to solve and must be obeyed. 
 * <ul>
 * <li> As you are programming you will also need to comment your code thoroughly in each of your methods.   
 * <li> You are only permitted to use the the specified methods in the java doc comments for each method. 
 * <li> The Predator array in your structure must always have only the space that is required.  
 * <li> You may create additional methods (private only) but they are still constrained by the rules of the calling method
 * <li> Make sure you set studentEmailID to your current email id (not student id)
 * </ul>
 * <p>
 * <strong>How We Will Mark Your Assignment.</strong>
 * <ul>
 * <li>We will run javadoc on your code to see if your code generates the API correctly.
 * <li>We will read your code to look for style and commenting problems.
 * <li>We will use the test driver to test your testing code. 
 * </ul>
 * <p>
 * <strong>Marking Scheme</strong><p>
 * 75 Percent for it working totally correct (eg no issues with the testing system). Note that some of the tests
 * will pass if you just fill in the method calls.  <strong>They will not get marks if they are side effects.</strong>  
 * There is <br>
 * 25 Percent for commenting/style of code etc...<br>
 * <p>
 * Hint:  Many of the more complicated methods can use the easier methods to do part of their job.  You 
 * will notice that some methods are only one or two lines long thats because I have taken advantage of
 * other methods to do the job.
 * 
 * <p>
 * Date 20160815
 * @version 1.5
 * @author ABEL GEBREMARIAM
 */
public class Pack {

      //Static initializer
      //like a constructor for static stuff
      public Pack(){
        studentEmailID = Pack.studentEmailID; 
      }




  /**
   * Fill this id in so the marking system looks pretty (and you get marks)
   */
  public static String studentEmailID = "gebam003";                                 //myid

  /**
   * This is a static initializer.   It is like a constructor for static values.
   * Don't stress too much about it.   Just understand that this code will run
   * the first time the virtual machine sees this class the static initializer will 
   * run.
   */
  {
    if (studentEmailID.equals("FILLTHISIN")) {
      System.out.println("Please set studentEmailID to your student ID now");
      System.exit(-1);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Predator list.   This contains the list of all Predators. 
   * The list should never contain a null in the middle and should never have more than one 
   * blank at the end (eg a null).
   */
  private Predator[] PredatorList = new Predator[100];                  //array declaration
  public int size=0;

  /**
   * Increase the array by one.  You will need to create a new array one element 
   * bigger than the old array. 
   * No External Classes Permitted to Be Used in This Method
   * My Solution Length in Lines (note yours can be longer or shorter): 3
   * 
   */

  //to increase the size of array
  private void increaseArray() {
        int temp= size++;                                                   //size increase
         Predator[] PredatorList =new Predator[temp];
  }

  /**
   * shrink the array by one.  You will need to create a new array one smaller 
   * than the current one then copy the old one into the new one.
   * This method should fail if the list is less than 1 in size, also if the last
   * element is not null.   
   * No External Classes Permitted to Be Used in This Method
   * My Solution Length in Lines (note yours can be longer or shorter): 9
   * 
   * @return true if it was successful false if unsuccessful
   */


 //decreasing the size of the array
  private boolean decreaseArray() {
      int temp=size--;
        if(temp>=0){
            Predator[] PredatorList=new Predator[temp];
            return true;
        }
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Return the Predator at the specific location in the list
   * If the Predator doesn't exist return null
   * No External Classes Permitted to Be Used in This Method
   * My Solution Length in Lines (note yours can be longer or shorter): 3
   * 
   * @param index the position to return.
   * @return The Predator at index or null if no Predator
   */

  //return predator at a location 
  public Predator getPredator(int index) {
      for(int i=0;i<PredatorList.length;i++){
          if(i==index){
          return (PredatorList[i]);                     //return the predator object
          }
      }
      return null ;

  }


  /**
   * Adds the provided Predator to the array.  You will need to increase
   * the array size and add the new Predator to the end of the list.  If the
   * name already exists (case does not matter) don't add the Predator and return -1.
   * No External Classes Permitted to Be Used in This Method Apart From 
   * String.toUpperClass and String.Equals
   * My Solution Length in Lines (note yours can be longer or shorter): 10
   * 
   * If the Predators status is dead do not add it to the list
   * @param newPredator the Predator to be added
   * @return the index of the new Predator -1 if unsuccessfully added 
   */

  //to add new predator
  public int addPredator(Predator newPredator) {
    int done=-1;
    for (int i=0;i<PredatorList.length;i++){
            PredatorList[i]=newPredator;
            done=(i+1);
        }
    return done;
  }

  /**
   * remove the Predator at the index.  
   * Pack the array and shrink the array when finished.
   * No External Classes Permitted to Be Used in This Method
   * My Solution Length in Lines (note yours can be longer or shorter): 4
   * 
   * @param index of the Predator to remove
   * @return the Predator removed.  If no Predator at the index return null.
   * 
   */

  //delete predator
  public Predator removePredator(int index) {
      int change=0;
      for(int i=0,j=0;i<PredatorList.length;i++){
          if(i!=index){
              PredatorList[j]=PredatorList[i];
              j++;
              change=1;                                     //alteration store
          }
      }
      if(change==1){
          return PredatorList[index+1];             
      }
      return null;
  }


  /**
   * remove the Predator at the index.  
   * Pack the array and shrink the array when finished.
   * (Note that you should do this method by using other methods)
   * No External Classes Permitted to Be Used in This Method
   * My Solution Length in Lines (note yours can be longer or shorter): 1
   * 
   * @param name The name of the Predator to remove
   * @return the Predator removed.  If no Predator at the index return null.
   * 
   */

  //remove predator with name 
  public Predator removePredator(String name) {
      for(int i=0,j=0;i<PredatorList.length;i++){
          name.toUpperCase();                                           //case change           
          if(PredatorList[i].getName().toUpperCase()!=name){            //skipping the same name predator  
              PredatorList[j]=PredatorList[i];                  
              j++;
          }
      }
      return null;
  }

  /**
   * returns the most damaged Predator.  Damage is measured by the difference between max hp and hp
   * No External Classes Permitted to Be Used in This Method.
   * My Solution Length in Lines (note yours can be longer or shorter): 10
   * 
   * @return the Predator with the most damage.  If there is nothing in the list return null.
   */
  public Predator mostDamagedPredator() {
    int resindex=-1;
    float max=PredatorList[0].getMaxHitPoints()-(PredatorList[0].getHitPoints());       //variable to store max damage
      for(int i=0;i<PredatorList.length;i++){
          float res=PredatorList[i].getMaxHitPoints()-PredatorList[i].getHitPoints();   //max damage calc for each predator
          if(res<max){                                                                  //checking max damage
              max=res;
              resindex=i;
          }
      }
     return PredatorList[resindex];

}


  /**
   * Damage the particular Predator at the index.  If the Predator is killed (eg damage greater
   * than the number of hit points.   The Predator should be removed from the list. 
   * No External Classes Permitted to Be Used in This Method Apart from String.equals.
   * My Solution Length in Lines (note yours can be longer or shorter): 9
   * 
   * @param index the Predator to damage
   * @param damage the amount of damage
   * @return true if the Predator was damaged
   */
  //damaging the predator
  public boolean damagePredator(int index, float damage) {
    boolean res=false;
    for(int i=0;i<PredatorList.length;i++){
        if(i==index){
            if((PredatorList[i].getHitPoints()-damage)>0){                      //checking for death or alive
                res=true;
                PredatorList[i].setHitPoints(PredatorList[i].getHitPoints()-damage);
            }
            if((PredatorList[i].getHitPoints()-damage)<0){                      //checking bounds
                removePredator(index);
            }
        }
    }
     return res;
  }


  /**
   * find the Predator with the particular name.
   * No External Classes Permitted to Be Used in This Method Apart from String.equals
   * My Solution Length in Lines (note yours can be longer or shorter): 3
   *
   * @param name the name of the Predator
   * @return the Predator with the name or null if not found
   */

  //searching using name
  public Predator findPredator(String name) {

      for(int i=0;i<PredatorList.length;i++){
         String temp= PredatorList[i].getName().toUpperCase();              //case change
          name.toUpperCase();                                               //case change
          if(temp.equals(name)){
              return (PredatorList[i]);
          }
      }
      return null;
  }


  /**
   * Do damage to all the Predators.
   * No External Classes Permitted to Be Used in This Method
   * My Solution Length in Lines (note yours can be longer or shorter): 5
   * 
   * @param damage damage to inflict on the pack
   * @return true if successful (at damaging the Pack)  false if no damage was done
   */

  public boolean PackDamage(float damage) {
      boolean done=true;
      for(int i=0;i<PredatorList.length;i++){  
          PredatorList[i].setHitPoints(PredatorList[i].getHitPoints()-damage);  //damage calculate for the pack
          if(PredatorList[i].getHitPoints()<0){
              done=false;                                                       //setting the check for the effect
          }
      }
      return done;
  }



  /**
   * Heal the named Predator up to its max hitpoints. 
   * No External Classes Permitted to Be Used in This Method
   * My Solution Length in Lines (note yours can be longer or shorter): 10
   * 
   * @param name name of the Predator to be healed.
   * @param amount the amount of hp to return to the Predator.
   * @return true if a Predator was successfully healed false if not.
   */
  public boolean heal(String name, float amount) {
    boolean res=false;
      for(int i=0;i<PredatorList.length;i++){
          name.toUpperCase();
          if(name.equals(PredatorList[i])){                                     //searching the list 
            PredatorList[i].setHitPoints(PredatorList[i].getHitPoints()+amount);
            res=true;
          }
      }
      return(res);
  }


  /**
   * Return the number of Predators in the list.
   * No External Classes Permitted to Be Used in This Method
   * My Solution Length in Lines (note yours can be longer or shorter): 1
   * 
   * @return the number of Predators
   */
  public int getNumberOfPredators() {
      int tot=PredatorList.length;                                          //size of the list
      return(tot);
  }


  /**
   * Get the total number of hit points for the Pack
   * No External Classes Permitted to Be Used in This Method
   * My Solution Length in Lines (note yours can be longer or shorter): 4
   * 
   * @return total hitpoints
   */
  public float totalHitPointsEntirePack() {
    float tot=0;
    for(int i=0;i<PredatorList.length;i++){
        tot+=PredatorList[i].getHitPoints();                            //summation of the pack hit points
    }
    return(tot);
  }

  /**
   * return the index of the Predator with the given name.  Case does not matter.
   * No External Classes Permitted to Be Used in This Method Apart from 
   * String.Equals and String.ToUpperCase
   * My Solution Length in Lines (note yours can be longer or shorter): 4
   * 
   * @param name the name of the Predator to be found
   * @return the position of the searched for Predator.  -1 if none found
   */
  public int indexOf(String name) {
      for(int i=0;i<PredatorList.length;i++){
          name.toUpperCase();
          if(name.equals(PredatorList[i])){                                 //finding the object with same name 
             return (i);  
          }
      }
    return -1;
  }

  /**
   * Have a battle between Predator one and Predator two. This should be done in a loop 
   * Where the Predators keep damaging each other until one of them dies. 
   * The winner is returned and the defeated is removed from the list. 
   * To keep it simple they do max damage to each other until one of them dies.
   * (We would normally use a Random value here but for testing we will just use max 
   * damage.
   * 
   * No External Classes Permitted to Be Used in This Method 
   * My Solution Length in Lines (note yours can be longer or shorter): 21
   *  
   * @param name1 Name of opponent 1
   * @param name2 Name of opponent 2
   * @return The Winner.  Or Null if the battle was not possible (eg one name didn't exist)
   */
  public Predator doBattle(String name1, String name2) {
    return null;
  }



  /**
   * Creates a list of Predators with their hit points in the following form
   *
<pre>
Pack of Predators
1 Giff * Current Health:10.0 * maxHitPoints=10.0hp
2 Neogi * Current Health:500.0 * maxHitPoints=500.0hp
3 Scavver * Current Health:120.0 * maxHitPoints=120.0hp
4 Man * Current Health:20.0 * maxHitPoints=20.0hp
5 Spaceworm * Current Health:10000.0 * maxHitPoints=10000.0hp
6 Minotaur * Current Health:250.0 * maxHitPoints=250.0hp
7 Lich * Current Health:300.0 * maxHitPoints=300.0hp
8 Naga * Current Health:150.0 * maxHitPoints=150.0hp
9 Beholder * Current Health:500.0 * maxHitPoints=500.0hp
10 Blazing Bones * Current Health:40.0 * maxHitPoints=40.0hp
11 Helmed Horror * Current Health:30.0 * maxHitPoints=30.0hp
12 Spider Dragon * Current Health:2500.0 * maxHitPoints=5000.0hp
</pre>
   * 
   * Note the formatting is done so that the output lines up in the columns 
   * Please use the most appropriate classes to help you do this method.
   * If you have nothing in the list it should report
<pre>
Pack of Predators
nil
</pre>
   * My Solution Length in Lines (note yours can be longer or shorter): 8
   * 
   */
  public String toString() {
    for(int i=0;i<PredatorList.length;i++){
        System.out.println((i+1)+PredatorList[i].getName()+ "*"
                + " " + "Current Health: "+ PredatorList[i].getHitPoints()
                +"* maxHitPoints="+ PredatorList[i].getMaxHitPoints()+ " hp");
    }
    return ("");
  }


  /**
   * Debug function for testing that things are working ok.
   * Dumps a printout of the current state of the Predators array
   * My Solution Length in Lines (note yours can be longer or shorter): 3
   */
  private void dumpAll() {
    for (int i=0;i<PredatorList.length;i++) {
      System.out.println(PredatorList[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate all your help, i am exhausted, i have spent days on it and i am not making any progress.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking here.  My best guess is that you are looking for help finishing the code to implement the comments.  If so, that would be off-topic here.  If it's something else, please provide more explanation.  Also, the title should be a quick summary of what the code does, not what you want from the review.

Answer (score 1):

Your homework you have to do yourself

Here you create a new array, but do not assign it to the array **field** with the same name. You made new object with a local name (hiding the field).

```
  private boolean decreaseArray() {
      int temp = size--;
      if (temp >= 0) {
          Predator[] PredatorList = new Predator[temp];
          return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
```

You could create a new smaller object as

```
  private boolean decreaseArray() {
      if (size > 0) {
          --size;
          Predator[] nextPredatorList = new Predator[size];
          System.arraycopy(PredatorList, 0, nextPredatorList, 0, size);
          PredatorList = nextPredatorList;
          return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
```

Or

```
  private boolean decreaseArray() {
      if (size > 0) {
          --size;
          PredatorList = Arrays.copy(PredatorList, 0, size);
          return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
```

Or simply use the larger array and limit access to `size`.

I think this captures most of you mental block.

Furthermore, Code Review is for the review of functioning code. Stack Overflow is more for code problems. And then don't "shout" in capitals.

As of review: let variable and field names start with a small letter, and use spaces. Accustom to it.